# iOS-Swift 5 After creating bridging header "MicrosoftCognitiveServicesSpeech-iOS/SPXSpeechApi.h" none of the classes are accessible

Tags: ios, swift, azure-cognitive-services

So I downloaded the MicrosoftCognitiveServicesSpeech-iOS SDK. I created bridging header for my Swift project. Everything works fine. But I try using the classes like SPXSpeechConfiguration, SPXAudioConfiguration. Complier unable to find these classes

I was able to use the Quickstart sample swift code.
I am using CocoaPods for installing the SDK, Xcode 13

My bridging header looks like this:

```
    #ifndef MicrosoftCognitiveServicesSpeech_iOS_Bridging_Header_h
    #define MicrosoftCognitiveServicesSpeech_iOS_Bridging_Header_h
    
    #import "MicrosoftCognitiveServicesSpeech-iOS/SPXSpeechApi.h"
    
    #endif /* MicrosoftCognitiveServicesSpeech_iOS_Bridging_Header_h */
```

Usage in my ViewController.swift file

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            var speechConfig: SPXSpeechConfiguration?
            let audioConfig = SPXAudioConfiguration()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try to add the framework you were trying to import inside the bridging header file to Target->Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries?

It should help. Thanks.